# How to set nTackPos value for scrollbar

Tags: windows, winapi, scrollbar

How to set `nTrackPos` value for the scrollbar? The [`SetScrollInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787595%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function ignores it.

Answer (score 2):

The `nTrackPos` member of the [`SCROLLINFO` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787537.aspx) is not set by the application, it is modified when the user drags the scrollbar (you will get a `WM_VSCROLL`/`WM_HSCROLL` message and can use GetScrollInfo to query it).

If you want to change the position if the scrollbar you need to set `nPos`.

Comment: What a dumb decision by the Win32 developers. Now there is no generic way to scroll a win32 window. Win32 is a good API but the widgets are not so good.